# Font/Fount of Information?

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns

I have seen it both ways:

> He is a veritable font of information.
>
> He is a veritable fount of information.

The first is referenced by [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/font)'s definition and seems to match the pronunciation I'm used to:

> source, fountain (a font of information)

The second seems equally sensible given that 'fount' can be an abbreviation for 'fountain'.

[An NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fount%20of%20information,font%20of%20information&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that 'fount' outpaces 'font' in written usage (seemingly in contradiction with the dictionary), but both seem to be pretty widespread.

Are there any reasons to use one over the other, or are they really wholly interchangeable?

Comment: Pretty much the same; they're just variant spellings of the same word that have drifted a bit, like _labor_ and _labour_.

Comment: @John Lawler: Granted, they're "the same" word. But unlike *labour/labor*, there's a difference in pronunciation. And to my mind, the *font* version has more mystic/religious connotations (a bit like *cornucopia* as opposed to *abundance*, perhaps).

Comment: As I said, they drifted. But they drifted different directions in different places, carrying different people on different voyages.

Comment: I have drunk from the font of others' wisdom and have been baptized in the font of their erudition. I write this as I sit at the soda fount-ain, delighting in the taste of a malted milkshake. I am still left in a quandary - not the Colorado mountain peak - when it comes to font vs. fount usage. But I do know the milkshake tastes good!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This usage is something of a "stock phrase" with *knowledge/wisdom*. Historically, *fount* has always been more common, but as [this NGram shows](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=font%20of%20wisdom,font%20of%20knowledge,fount%20of%20wisdom,fount%20of%20knowledge&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), *font* is rapidly catching up...

[image]

I don't think there's any difference in meaning, or in UK/US spelling preferences. But personally, I've always thought *fount* here sounds a bit quaint/archaic - perhaps I'm just [ahead of my time](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_dos_the_idiom_ahead_of_his_time_mean).

It's worth pointing out that OP's exact phrasing (with the *very* quaint/archaic use of *veritable*) simply reflects the fact that all variants are normally used somewhat facetiously.

Comment: Yes, since font is the spelling used for "typeface" everywhere, I suppose it is the natural choice nowadays, +1.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: I hadn't even thought of that, but I suppose it could well be an influence. Nevertheless, I think the gradual rise of *font* was well underway long before most of us ever had much reason to think of *font - typeface*, so I doubt very much it's the whole story.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Perhaps it's an Americanism, but I hear 'veritable font/fount' used with reasonable frequency, without meaning it to be facetious.

Comment: Comic Sans is certainly [not](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=people+who+hate+comic+sans&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) a font of wisdom.

Comment: @Lynn: Umm - really? In how many other contexts do Americans habitually use *veritable* in a "non-facetious" way? I mean the choice of that word is usually somewhat self-conscious/jocose, not that the statement including it is untrue or otherwise not to be taken seriously.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Oh, not in any other contexts, just in this one.   It's like you said - a stock phrase  "veritable font of information/wisdom/knowledge".

Comment: @Lynn: Yes, well [usage has fallen 80% or so](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+is+a+veritable&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) over the past century, so I think most speakers would realise it's a somewhat "quirky" thing to say. The "natural" phrasing today would be ***real** font (or **mine**) of information*. Perhaps we just had different definitions of "facetious" there.

Comment: Presumably a 'font' is  real object people know about while 'fount' is a more archaic/poetic term for a water source - so people are becoming more comfortable with 'font'

Comment: @mgb: Actually, I'd think it would be the other way around: _fount_ is short for _fountain_ just like _mount_ is short for _mountain_ – but what's a _font_, unless we are talking about letters and serifs?  Maybe how "archaic" _fount_ sounds depends on whether your neck of the woods is more inclined to say _water bubbler_, or _water fountain_ (I don't know; that's just a theory).

Comment: @J.R.: It's virtually always the [baptismal font](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=baptismal+fount%2Cbaptismal+font&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) (not *fount*) - so as mgb says, that's a word we're at least familiar with outside of archaic/poetic contexts. Even though less people go to church baptisms (in the UK, at least), the word "font" will probably be kept alive by the stock phrase, if nothing else.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Good point (although that meaning of font is still derived from _fountain_, [evidently](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=font&allowed_in_frame=0)).

Comment: @Carlo_R. _Font_, when meaning "printed characters or letters", is from late 16th century. I am not sure it would explain using _font_ instead of _fount_. The NOAD says that _fount_ is also used in British English instead of _font_ (the type). I cannot say how often _fount_ would be used in that case, though.

Comment: @kiama, yes, but popular interpretation of a word's meaning can alter its spelling in the course of time, neverthless you are right: "fount" has became the standard term among printers in Britain. Maybe Andrew Leach could confirm, if any.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: I've worked closely with many UK printers, publishers, and typesetters over several decades, and I can assure you I've *never* heard anyone refer to type fonts as "founts". Even on the UK corpus, *print fount* flatlines against [print font](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=print+fount%2Cprint+font&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) in Google Books.

Comment: ...also note that *type font* had already overtaken [type fount](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=type+fount%2Ctype+font&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) before the strikes in the mid-80s that heralded the introduction of modern technology into UK newspaper printing. But from then on, *fount* rapidly sank without trace.

Answer (score 6):

From The American Heritage Dictionary comes the 
following:

> **font** *n.*
>   1. A basin for holding baptismal water in a church.
>   2. A receptacle for holy water; a stoup.
>   3. The oil reservoir in an oil-burning lamp.
>   4. An abundant source; a fount: She was a font of wisdom and good sense.

It seems, then, we have a case of potato-potahto.  Either
word—font or fount—is perfectly appropriate.  I happen
to prefer "font".

Answer (score 4):

> Are there any reasons to use one over the other, or are they really wholly interchangeable?

The spelling *fount* survives in poetic diction as a synonym for fountain, and in more general use as a figurative word for "source," as in "fount of wisdom." (Reference: "Handbook of Varieties of English," Kortmann)

So, according to Kortmann's book, it seems these word are not **wholly** interchangeable and  you should use *font* for the ceremonial "baptismal font."

Comment: This is one of those cases where etymology and relative prevalence in other contexts doesn't really make any difference. It's just a stock phrase where both words are commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

I grew up in the UK, where "fount" was always the normal usage in this phrase. "Font" in this context still makes me stop and think; in my British brain, a "font" is a typeface or a baptismal basin.

Answer (score -2):

It's definitely a fount of wisdom, taken from fountain. Fount is a convenient shortening of the word often used by poets to fit rhymes, and has since become in popular use. Definitely not font which has always been a baptismal vessel.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary lists the third definition of "font" as "fount n.1   Now only poet.". There are examples from 1611 on.